# How to fix \useshorthands \defineshorthand usage on bookmark entries?

Tags: babel, hyphenation, hyphenat

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{abntex2}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{hyphenat}

\useshorthands{~}\defineshorthand{~=}{\hyp{}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First~=Chapter}

\end{document}
```

Instead of `~=` to become `-` (hyphen) on my bookmarks entries, it become `=` (a space and an equal sign):

[image: z]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hyperref` doesn't let you do that, apparently. A bit hackish, but try this (this assumes that whatever `~` in a section title will become a valid pdf string):

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{abntex2}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{hyphenat}

\makeatletter
\def\HyPsd@LetUnexpandableSpace#1{%
  \if\noexpand~\noexpand#1%
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi{\expandafter\futurelet\expandafter#1\expandafter\@gobble\space\relax}}
\makeatother

\useshorthands{~}
\defineshorthand{~=}{\hyp{}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First~=Chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]